# Core Data relationship with parameter in relationship

Tags: core-data, entity, relationship

I have a Core Data project and I want to have a relationship between 2 people, but I want to be able to set or change the type of the relationship between the 2 people.

Let's say I have a Core Data Entity named "Person", and I make a relationship between "Person" and "Person", and I call this the biologicalFatherSon - relationship, and the inverse the biologicalSonFather - relationship.
This will work fine. Now I want to add an adoptionFatherSon - relationship, and a guardian, stepfather, foster ... relationship. For all these situations I could create relationships, but I'd prefer to create a relationship between 2 people, and set as type as biological, adoption, seal, foster... There would be one 1 relationship, but I can set the type as a parameter somewhere.

How can I do that with Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to implement *relationships* between two Core Data entities is exactly as you point out. This is different from ordinary relational databases that are not modelled as "object graphs", in that you do not need a "join table", because the Core Data framework manages that for you.

However, you want to model a *human relationship*, so perhaps there is a confusion of terms.

In Core Data, if you want to record *additional information about a relationship*, you use join tables. E.g.

```
Person <-------->> Relationship <<--------> Person
```

where `Relationship` is another entity with an attribute `type` that describes the relationship further.